# Tool to Support Advanced Search

Tags: plugins, frameworks, content-management-system, advanced-search

I am not quite sure how to ask this and if my title is correct. Please edit this question if seen fit.

Redmine has a feature where user can filter certain user defined parameters when performing search:

[image: remdine search issue]

I would like to know if there is a term for this kind of feature so I can research more regarding this. I'd also like to know if there are existing technologies (i.e. frameworks/cms/plugin) that support this kind of feature. I want to reuse exising technologies if possible and at the same time have this kind of search feature.

My requirements are similar to that of Redmine. That is, instead of Issues, I search Users and the attributes related to that user. The requirements are as follows:

- I can add a user, specify the attributes related to this user.
- Perform a search on the user and specify the parameters where to the search the user.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that there is no real term for this, beyond "advanced search"; unfortunately these functions range from simple to mind-bogglingly advanced.